# I have a date column created with a case statement. How do I make an ELSE condition where 'N/A' is present if the values in the cell are NULL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, coalesce, isnull

Whenever I try to remove `1900-01-01` and use `N/A`, I get this error:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "N/A"

I want a situation where `'N/A'` appears instead of `1900-01-01`.

This is my code:

```
case 
    when lead(ens.start) over (partition by patient order by ens.start asc) <= ens.start + INTERVAL '90 day' 
        then lead(ens.start) over (partition by patient order by ens.start asc) 
        else coalesce(lead(ens.start) over (partition by patient order by ens.start asc), '1900-01-01') 
end as first_readmission_date
```

Comment: Well, `N/A` is not a valid date. And it's a CASE _expression_ not a statement. If you want to represent a missing date use `NULL`

Comment: Yes! Exactly, but this is a test/assignment and I was asked to use 'N/A' as a provision in the "ELSE" part of the CASE statement. I'm thinking of using '1990-01-01' and making a point to bring that up when I submit. Because I'm done with the rest of the query. What do you think?

Comment: Then you can't return a DATE value, you must return a string (`text`)  value

Comment: converd all return values into text

Answer (score 1):

Like @a_horse_with_no_name said 'N/A' is not a valid date. The SQL value for missing value is `null` (if your column in nullable).

If you want to visualize 'N/A', my preference would be to go with `null` and sort this in the visualization layer (if you have one).

Otherwise, you can try to convert the dates returned by the CASE expression to strings.

Something like:

```
case 
  when lead(ens.start) over (partition by patient order by ens.start asc) <= ens.start + INTERVAL '90 day' 
    then to_char(lead(ens.start), 'YYYY-MM-DD') over (partition by patient order by ens.start asc) 
  else 
    coalesce(to_char(lead(ens.start), 'YYYY-MM-DD')  over (partition by patient order by ens.start asc),'N/A') 
end as first_readmission_date
```